# ASP.NET Core - calling method inside top-level statements

Tags: c#, .net-core

I'm making a .NET Core Web API project with C# 9.0 top-level statements. In previous versions of .NET Web API we had Startup.cs file in which there were methods like **ConfigureServices()** and **Configure()**.

I need to call method of my custom class and in previous version's Startup.cs I was going like this:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services) 
{
    // Registration my class in DI container
    services.AddScoped<RestaurantSeeder>();
    // ...
}
 
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment, RestaurantSeeder seeder)
{
    // Calling method of my custom class
    seeder.Seed();
    // ...
}
```

Just like above, I was registering the class in DI container inside **ConfigureServices()** method, and inside **Configure()** method I could inject some dependency (in here **RestaurantSeeder**) and finally I could call some method of injected class (in here **Seeder()**).

The question is: How to achieve this with top-level statements? I know how to register classes in DI containers but now how can I call the **Seed** method of **RestaurantSeeder** class?

Thanks in advance for all replies!

Comment: Why not just keep using a Startup class?

Comment: You can define classes and methods _after_ the top level main. Or just put them in separate files. Top level statements only add value for very small projects. For everything more complex, just use the old ways

Comment: @JHBonarius I already have top-level statements and don't wanna create new project. I can call this method in seperate file and class but.. I have to declare new object of this class somewhere anyways :D I can do it in top-level statements but then I need to declare it by hand like this:
`
var obj = new ClassCallingSeederMethod();
`
...so I cannot register this class in DI container. Do I get it correctly?

Comment: What is `Seed` doing? When should it be called? Does it need other dependencies? How is the ` RestaurantSeeder` registered?